# accessing table attribute from anothe one

Tags: asp.net, sql, web-services

in SQL, if i have a table with column A and B and others, and i need to get the values of the other columns through web service that takes a value of attribute of B as an input, however i only know the A value.
how can i get the value of attribute B using the known A in order to invoke the web service? 
sending a query to retrieve B is an option but i don't know the name of the table
thanks in advance
`<ABSENCE_DELAY_DATA xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <B>string</B>
    </ABSENCE_DELAY_DATA>`

Comment: Let me rephrase your example: _I have the `Username` column value and I want to pass it to the web service which takes the `Password` column value as a parameter. Is there a way to get make it work?_ :)

Comment: okay thanks everyone it seems that they forgot to give the table name :)